# VSCode snippets refresh required after change?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

After changeing an user snippet I,d like to use it.

Is there any other way to update the snippets besides restarting VSCode?

Comment: the snippet is active the moment you save the snippet file

Comment: I saw this on one system, but not at an other one. So I'm still investigating - there are some ohter behaviors that seems special in vscode at this system.

Comment: If you don't seem them updating after saving the file, [file an issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new/choose)

Answer (score 2):

Simply save the snippet file.

If still doesn't works, do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, type reload window and press enter.

Comment: This worked for me.

Comment: Just saving has never worked for me when it feels like it should, but reloading the windows does the trick!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I put my snippet in the wrong Snippet file. For example, I wanted to write a new snippet for creating a React Funcition Component like so:

```json
{
    // Place your snippets for typescriptreact here. Each snippet is defined under a snippet name and has a prefix, body and
    // description. The prefix is what is used to trigger the snippet and the body will be expanded and inserted. Possible variables are:
    // $1, $2 for tab stops, $0 for the final cursor position, and ${1:label}, ${2:another} for placeholders. Placeholders with the
    // same ids are connected.
    // Example:
    // "Print to console": {
    //  "prefix": "log",
    //  "body": [
    //      "console.log('$1');",
    //      "$2"
    //  ],
    //  "description": "Log output to console"
    // }
    "React Function Component": {
        "prefix": "reactfc",
        "body": [
            "export type ${2:Props} = {",
            "};",
            "",
            "export const ${1:Component}: React.FC<${2:Props}> = props => {",
            "  return (",
            "    <>$0</>",
            "  );",
            "};"
        ],
        "description": "Create a new React Function Component with types"
    }
}
```

But I accidentally put it in the `typescript.json` snippets file instead of the `typescriptreact.json` snippets file. Moving it into the right snippets file made it be picked up correctly. That could be the problem here.

At any rate, I'm writing this answer here because this is the search that came up when trying to find a solution to this problem.